# tsc using glob pattern for multiple extensions

Tags: typescript, tsc

I run this cmd `npx -p typescript tsc config/**/*.{m,}js --declaration ...` to emit the declaration files for both .mjs and .js files

but I got this error `File 'config/**/*.{m,}js' has an unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are ...`

how can I tell tsc to deal with all .js and .mjs in the specified path without creating a tsconfig.json file specially for this cmd?

Comment: Why do you want to compile .js files? Shouldn't it be `.{m,}ts`?

Comment: the question still the same, anyway, you may want to provide .js files to tsc just to emit its corresponding declarations.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, typescript doesn't automatically emit declarations for a javascript file. The error which is omitted in the question is exactly stating that it only accept typescript files as input

Comment: I already use this feature, I just ask about the glob pattern issue.

Comment: The problem is not the glob pattern, but js is an unsupported extension

Comment: yes, confirmed by typescript team @BrunoMarotta